# Django migrations - Populate empty fields by coping already existing field

Tags: python, django, database-migration, django-migrations

I have a problem with making migrations after changing my model. I changed already exisitnig DateField (*lectures_begginning*) from `null=true` to `null=false`. Now I have to populate old entries. Fortunately I have existing DateField (*semester_begginning*) which was always set to `null=false`. Usually these two differ by 4-5 days so I can just copy the *semester_beggining*.

```
class Semester(models.Model):

    lectures_beginning = models.DateField(
        null=False, verbose_name='Class start day')
    semester_beginning = models.DateField(
        null=False, verbose_name='Semester start day')
```

How can I change migration so it copies value of *semester_beginning* to *lectures_beginning* only if latter is NULL?

```
from django.db import migrations, models

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('courses', '0034_auto_20201106_2039'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='semester',
            name='lectures_beginning',
            field=models.DateField(verbose_name='Dzień rozpoczęcia zajęć'),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling data during django migrations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65590687/handling-data-during-django-migrations)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `make_migration` to create an empty migration.  Then add a `RunPython` operation to the new migration's `operations` list.

Here is an example (from the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/#data-migrations)):

```
from django.db import migrations

def combine_names(apps, schema_editor):
    # We can't import the Person model directly as it may be a newer
    # version than this migration expects. We use the historical version.
    Person = apps.get_model('yourappname', 'Person')
    for person in Person.objects.all():
        person.name = '%s %s' % (person.first_name, person.last_name)
        person.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('yourappname', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(combine_names),
    ]
```

As noted in the comment, you must use `apps` to retrieve Model instances because you need a version that is compatible with database schema at a specific point in the migration history.

In your case, you could query all `Semester` objects where `lectures_beginning` is null.  Then iterate the objects in the result list, copying the field for the object and then saving the object.  (I don't think there is a clever way to do this that avoids writing some python code.)

Note that this data migration needs to happen before the migration with the `AlterField`.   I would recommend keeping schema and data migration operations into separate migrations.  (I don't know if it will work if you try to combine them.)